# Return statusCode with message in fileFilter multer

Tags: node.js, express, file-upload, error-handling, multer

I want to make a filter for uploaded files using multer package, and my validation works.

But I want when user send wrong files, I return statusCode and message together.

NOTE: I can send message or send statusCode but I want send both.

here is my code

```
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from "uuid"
import multer from "multer";

const AVAILABLE_IMAGE_FORMATS = ["image/jpg", "image/jpeg", "image/png", "image/gif"]
const __dir_images__ = `${__dirname__}/../uploads/images`

class HandledRespError {
  constructor(statusCode = 500, message = Messages.failed) {
    return {
      statusCode: statusCode,
      message: message
    }
  }
}

const multerStorageFileName = function(req, file, cb) {
  const uniqueName = uuidv4() + "--" + file.originalname
  return cb(null, uniqueName)
}

const imageStorage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: __dir_images__,
  filename: multerStorageFileName
});

const imageFileFilter = function(req, file, cb) {
  if ( ! AVAILABLE_IMAGE_FORMATS.includes(file.mimetype) ) return cb(new HandledRespError(406), false) // I think my problem is here

  cb(null, true)
}

export const imageUpload = multer({storage: imageStorage, fileFilter: imageFileFilter})
```

if I use `return cb( "my message", false)` or `return cb( new Error("my message"), false)`
it will return my message with statusCode 500.

if I send `return cb({statusCode:406, message: "my message"}, false)` or `return cb({status:406, message: "my message"}, false)`, it will return statusCode 406 and message will be `[object object]`

how can I handle both statusCode and message together?

[image: this is postman response]

**UPDATE:**

I use `const exeption = new Error("Operation Failed!"); exeption.statusCode = 406`. It worked but I got some other messages and I don't want these messages.

result of new code:

[image]

And one more thing, how can I change html response to JSON response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `statusCode` property on the error object rather than passing it as a parameter:

```
var err = new Error("error 406");
err.statusCode = 406;
return cb(err);
```

How this error is ultimately presented to the client depends on the express [error handler](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html). See the linked documentation for how the standard error handler behaves and how you can write you own.

Comment: thanks, it works, now I have one another issue, in this way I get the system error message with my message

Comment: <pre>Error: Operation Failed!<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at videoFileFilter (file:///C:/NodeJS/webArRestAPI/app/middlewares/fileUpload.js:34:15)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at wrappedFileFilter (C:\NodeJS\webArRestAPI\node_modules\multer\index.js:44:7)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at Multipart.&lt;anonymous&gt; (C:\NodeJS\webArRestAPI\node_modules\multer\lib\make-middleware.js:107:7)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at Multipart.emit (node:events:390:28)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at HeaderParser.cb (C:\NodeJS\webArRestAPI\node_modules\busboy\lib\types\multipart.js:358:14)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at HeaderParser.push </pre>

Comment: how can I avoid default error message?

Comment: Please update your question with your current code.